# How lion can carry the cub without harming it?

Tags: zoology

We can see in the picture that lion is carrying its cub by the **scruff of its neck** without causing harm to it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The skin of the felines has geneticaly evolved in such a way that the parent can do this.

Its strong and stretchy in the neck area.

Moreover, the cub enters into an obedient state.

Comment: Too complicated. I was going to answer but know I would get "dinged" because people on here seem to prefer the complex over the simple. The answer is "They don't bite down". Thats it. You can prove it to yourself. Put your finger in your mouth, and close your teeth around it. What keeps you from biting your finger off? : Intent.

Comment: @KarlKjer — Answer in answers or not at all. Comments are explicitly not for answers. It's a pretty naive question that demands a straightforward answer. If people 'ding' you just shrug it off.

Comment: just try to "ding" a human and see where is going :)